# Converting Fractions in a Dataframe Series to Float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fractions

In Python 3.x, how can I convert a Dataframe column containing fraction strings and NaN values into floats? I've tried a few things but haven't found an adequate solution.

So if I have a dataframe, "df", that looks like:

```
     a      b
0   John   20/1
1   Bob    NaN
2   Tim    9/2
```

How can I end up with df looking like:

```
      a      b
0   John   20.0
1   Bob    1000.0
2   Tim    4.5
```

Thank you for any guidance you're willing to provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic of `eval` from `pandas`

```
df.b=pd.eval(df.b.fillna(1000))
df
Out[25]: 
      a     b
0  John    20
1   Bob  1000
2   Tim   4.5
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it! Thank you.

Comment: Nice anwer, very easy and I did not know about eval

Answer (score 1):

Or with `apply`:

```
df.b = df.b.fillna(1000).apply(pd.eval)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
      a       b
0  John    20.0
1   Bob  1000.0
2   Tim     4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

`df = df.fillna(1000.0)`

`df.b = [eval(str(e)) for e in df.b]`

Answer (score 0):

```
df['b'] = pd.eval(df['b'].fillna(1000.0))
df.head()
```

Comment: You should also add an explanation