# Identifying value in dataframe as Integer or Mixed Fraction and convert each to Float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, fractions

Program is to compile baseball stats for a KBO fantasy baseball league. Program uses rosters from Excel file to scrape data from webpages like this one - http://eng.koreabaseball.com/Teams/PlayerInfoPitcher/GameLogs.aspx?pcode=65320 - and to append the new, daily stats to a data set against which reports and analyses are run.

```
    MAY    OPP    ERA  RES  PA     IP  H  HR  BB  HBP  K  R  ER   OAVG
0  5.06     SK   6.23  NaN  18  4 1/3  3   2   1    0  5  3   3  0.188
1  5.12    KIA   0.00  NaN  25      7  1   0   3    0  8  0   0  0.045
2  5.17  LOTTE   1.29  NaN  26      7  2   1   3    0  6  1   1  0.087
3  5.23     NC   3.18    L  27  5 2/3  7   0   3    1  6  2   2  0.304
4  5.29     SK  14.73    L  20  3 2/3  7   2   2    0  2  6   6  0.389,     
    JUN     OPP  ERA RES  PA  IP  H  HR  BB  HBP  K  R  ER  OAVG
0  6.04  KIWOOM  6.0   L  26   6  8   2   1    0  8  4   4  0.32
```

The "IP" column (innings pitched) is stored as integer OR mixed fraction. Converting both to float would probably be the easiest.

```
from fractions import Fraction

def mixed_to_float(x):
    return float(sum(fractions.Fraction(term) for term in x.split()))

    for i, df in enumerate(dfpitcher):
            # I need to manipulate the IP to convert it to float; I've tried several approaches. 
            # Closest attempt thus far. The "innings_pitched variable returns the Index, the value, the name, and the dtype.
            innings_pitched = todaystats['IP']

            print(player_name,' had innings pitched: ', innings_pitched)
            todaystats.loc[((todaystats['IP'] >= 6) | (todaystats['ER'] <= 3)),'QS'] = 1
```

Current result is >= on between instances of str and int not supported.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To hep you, we need to understand what data you're working with. Additionally, you've posted a ton of code and context here that presumably has nothing to do with converting integers and fractions to floats. Can you develop a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which clearly and simply demonstrates the issue you're facing and where it's going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the edits - this is a muuuuch clearer question for us to tackle! Appreciate the responsiveness.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Fractions in a Dataframe Series to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349133/converting-fractions-in-a-dataframe-series-to-float)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that having those extra rows in there (as the headers for each month) is whats bugging it up. You can't change 'IP' string to a float/int. I'd consider changing the Month column `'MAY'`, `'JUNE'`, etc. to simply `'DATE'`, then convert to a ctual date (I'm assuming this is 2020 season? Although are they playing baseball in Korean league?)

Then just apply a function to convert:

```
import pandas as pd
from fractions import Fraction

def mixed_to_float(ip):
    try:
        ip = str(ip)
        if len(ip.split()) > 1:
            ipFloat = ip.split()
            ipFloat = (int(ipFloat[0]) + float(Fraction(ipFloat[-1])))
        else:
            ipFloat = float(ip)
        return ipFloat
    except:
        return ip


url = 'http://eng.koreabaseball.com/Teams/PlayerInfoPitcher/GameLogs.aspx?pcode=65320'
dfs = pd.read_html(url, converters={0: str})  #<-- changed here   

results = pd.DataFrame()
for df in dfs:
    df['IP'] = df['IP'].apply(mixed_to_float)
    df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:'DATE'})
    df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].astype(str) + '.2020'
    df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
    df['DATE'] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.date())
    results = results.append(df, sort=False)
results = results.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
         DATE      OPP    ERA  RES  PA        IP  H  HR  BB  HBP  K  R  ER   OAVG
0  2020-05-07      KIA   3.60  NaN  24  5.000000  9   0   2    0  4  2   2  0.409
1  2020-05-13  SAMSUNG   2.45    L  27  7.333333  4   0   0    0  6  4   2  0.154
2  2020-05-19       SK  13.50  NaN  17  2.666667  4   0   4    0  2  5   4  0.308
3  2020-05-24    LOTTE   1.50    L  23  6.000000  5   0   0    0  3  1   1  0.217
4  2020-05-03       KT   3.00    W  22  6.000000  5   1   0    0  5  2   2  0.238
5  2020-06-05       LG   2.57    W  26  7.000000  5   1   0    0  4  2   2  0.192
```

Comment: Focusing on date conversion (though, now 2021), code result above is: `ParserError: Unknown string format: 2021-04-03.2021`

I worked through code line by line; these two lines produce the correct date format: 
`df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].astype(str) + '.2020'
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])`

However, because the Date column is dtype float64, the 4.10 of the month loses the trailing 0 when using astype(str), so what should be 4.10 is 4.1 and becomes 4/1/2021 and not 4/10/2021. Is there a way to force the trailing zero in the float value 4.10 to be included in the str conversion?

Comment: I did finally find a way to make this work within the context of my code. Commenting out `df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.date())` and adding `df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].dt.date` got it to the format I could use. Prior to that it was landing in the datetime64[ns] format. It took me a while, but I finally got there. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the mixed fraction issue. Learned enough over time that I was able to modify the function to meet the need.

The IP values are one of three types

- integer (1 - 9)
- mixed fraction (int 1-9 combined with 1/3 or 2/3)
- fraction (1/3 or 2/3 are the only options

I modified mixed_to_float to handle each, in that order. I know the code can be simplified/more efficient by more experienced programmers, but this worked for me.

```
from fractions import Fraction

def mixed_to_float(ip):
    try:
        ip = str(ip)
        if len(ip) == 1:
            ipFloat = float(ip)
        elif len(ip.split()) > 1:
            ipFloat = ip.split()
            y = ipFloat[1]
            x = y.split('/')
            z = (float(x[0]) / float(x[1]))  
            ipFloat = (int(ipFloat[0]) + z )
        else:
            x = ip.split('/')
            ipFloat = (float(x[0]) / float(x[1]))           
        return ipFloat
    except:
        print('Mixed_to_Float ERROR on',ip)
        return ip
```